# QT-OpenGl Vertex not redrawing

Tags: qt, opengl

I have a simple openGl program that should redrawn when i change a spinner.
When the paintGL method is invoked the color of my vertex triangles change but the number of them (that is based on the spinner ) don't.

My code is the following:

```
            void  GLWidget::paintGL()
            {

                glLoadIdentity();
                glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR) ;
                glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                for(int i=0;i<numVertex;i++){
                    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
                        drawTriangle(i);
                    glEnd();
                }
             qDebug("numVetex %d",numVertex);

            };
           void GLWidget::drawTriangle(int iteraction){

                float theta=thetaIncrement*iteraction;
                float x=  radius*qCos(theta);
                float y=radius*qSin(theta);
                double r=((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
                double g=((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
                double b=((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
                glColor3f(r,g,b);
                glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                glVertex3f(x,y,0.0f);
                theta=thetaIncrement*(iteraction+1);
                x= radius*qCos(theta);
                y=radius*qSin(theta);
                glVertex3f( x,y, 0.0f);

            }
```

Even if i don't draw anything for example, on even number of vertex i just put a return on paintGl , the already drawn vertex still are showed on the screen.

Any recommendation?

Comment: you shouldn't add GL_COLOR to the clear call

Comment: Solved it. Thanks , answer please so i can accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your glClear call doesn't have a valid argument remove the GL_COLOR part:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) ;
```